# How to capture dynamic input in table populated from database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

The title says everything, i want to capture the input field in the table as i'm making an ordering form. The tbody data is populated from database through select option (Supplier).

All help are appreciated guys. Thank you.

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="supplier" required>
    <option disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
    <?php
    while($rowname = mysqli_fetch_array($allsup2))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$rowname['sup'].'">'.$rowname['sup'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<table id="resultTable" style="position: relative;" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="60%" class="small">Name</th>
        <th width="40%" class="small">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $supplier = $_POST['supplier'];                         
            $query = "SELECT * FROM supplies where supplier='$supplier'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $result_array[] = $results;
            }                       
            echo '<form method="post">';
            foreach ($result_array as $result)
            {
                echo '<tr>';            
                echo '<td class="small">'.$result['product'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="small"><input type="text" name="'.$result['id'].'"/></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Order now" class="right s-12 btn btn-default" />
</form>


<?php 
if(isset($_post['submit2']))
{
    //capturing input field to put in the order cart
}   
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using the `$result['id']` as the `<input>` name value, it would be easier if you used it as an array key, ie. `name=dynamic["'.$result['id'].'"]`. Then in php, you can loop over those with a `foreach()` -> `foreach($_POST['dynamic'] as $key => $value){....}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, if i use `foreach($_POST['dynamic'] as $key => $value)`, how can i call the product name from the database ? can i use this ? `($combine($_POST['dynamic'], $result_array) as $result => $key)` ?